# Gradle stuck at building project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio, and every time Gradle attempts to build my project, it gets stuck. What I mean by that is it gives me the build dialog for hours at a time, and I am unable to build my project. Here is a screenshot:[Android Studio Gradle Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgalQ.jpg)

I have scoured what seems like the entire whole of the internet, but no solution I have found seems to work. I am new to Android development, so there is probably something here that's staring me straight in the face. The main thing that sticks out to me is this portion of the logs in my .gradle directory:

```js
DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
16:20:23.790 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonStatus] GC rate: 0.0/s
16:20:23.793 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:20:23.795 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
16:20:23.803 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:21:23.790 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
16:21:23.791 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonStatus] GC rate: 0.0/s
16:21:23.794 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:21:23.795 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
16:21:23.800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:22:23.792 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
16:22:23.793 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonStatus] GC rate: 0.0/s
16:22:23.798 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:22:23.799 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
16:22:23.806 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:23:23.794 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
16:23:23.795 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonStatus] GC rate: 0.0/s
16:23:23.800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
16:23:23.800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
16:23:23.807 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

As you can see, this sequence repeats itself over and over again. I am 100% positive I have the correct gradle installation, I just can't seem to figure out why my project refuses to build.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
I just wanted to let everyone know that I figured it out! Apparently my parents put some insanely powerful parental control software on my computer a few years ago and I forgot it was there. After uninstalling, Android Studio now works flawlessly. The software basically blocked all unknown traffic coming in and out of most of the ports. Anyway, thank you to everyone for the help. I can finally start developing!

Comment: change your Oracle Java JDK to 8 version and set it in `file -> project structure`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wanted to let everyone know that I figured it out! Apparently my parents put some insanely powerful parental control software on my computer a few years ago and I forgot it was there. So if any of you have Qustodio Parental Control on your computer, beware that it will prevent you from doing anything related to software development. After uninstalling, Android Studio now works flawlessly. The software basically blocked all unknown traffic coming in and out of most of the ports. Anyway, thank you to everyone for the help. I can finally start developing!

Answer (score 0):

I once had this same issue and after some struggle i found a temporary solution to this problem, later on I updated my AS and JDK to latest version and the problem was resolved.

Temporary solution: After you see the same sequence starts to show in log, just simply start TaskManager and kill java process. It will stop this never ending loop of gradle build and your app will be installed on device(emulator or physical) without any issues.

Later on you can update AS and JDK to latest versions and be sure to provide valid path to JDK.

Comment: That does work, but my AS and jdk are the latest versions. Is it possible to use maven instead of gradle to build projects?

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. and about Maven over Gradle preference. The later build tool uses the best practices/ideas of maven and execute with perfection and gradle can help you with lots of external libraries for your projects but maven is somehow not that flexible. There are different opinions about the two build tools. you can do your research and try for yourself. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you are on **`windows`**,

Try deleting your `.gradle` from `C:\Users\<username>` directory and try again.

**or**

go to **`Android Studio -> Preferences -> Gradle ->`** and tick **`Offline work`**.

sometimes it also work following way

**`File Menu - > Invalidate Caches/ Restart->Invalidate and Restart`**.

Comment: I have tried them all, many times, repeatedly, without any luck. The error still persists.

Comment: can you tell me version of `android studio` and your `OS`

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.1.3 and i am on Windows 10